# AMP HTML & GTM/Analytics - Tracking iFrame Form Submission

Tags: amp-html

the setup: AMP HTML Page with GTM Integration. The AMP HTML page loads my own form wizard via amp-iframe.

Now i want to track the submissions (from the iframe) via Google Analytics.

Is there any way?

EDIT: On the parent page, GTM is integrated with AMP via the new AMP Support/ AMP Container.

The Question is: How can i track the submissions in the amp-iframe. I can use GTM on the iframe content/child but then GA Tracks 2 Times: ones when AMP Page is loaded with the AMP GTM and then when iframe loads with the "normal" GTM?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Would it be possible to migrate your form wizard to AMP? This would solve your problem and the UX would be better without iframes as well.

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution: Track the form submission via Measurement Protocol https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events

and make sure that the cliend id are the same via https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/google-analytics-client-id-amp-pages/

Best,
Daniel

Comment: This is one of the way to do it and ensure that it tracks the action correctly. However, you can also set analytics in the iframe, not track the pageview and only track the form submission event.

Answer (score 0):

Tag Mangager (with [Analytics](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106924)) ist now [Supported](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7086920?hl=en) in AMP without Iframe. But not with 100% Support.
I think for future Support you should use this solution.